# Checking a map is not a translation of another map

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symplectic-geometry

Let $\psi_t$ be a flow of a killing vector field with period one in $(\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^n,\omega_{FS})$ with the property that it's perpendicular to $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$, for the fubini study metric, and hence it will be perpendicular to $\psi_t(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n)$. Now consider $\phi_t=\psi_{t/2^N}$, for some large enough $N$. Now let $u$ be a $J$-Holomorphic map from $\mathbb{R}\times [0,1]$ with the property that $u(\tau,0)\subset \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ and $u(\tau,1)\subset \phi_1(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n)$. It's easy to see that $\phi_1^{2^N}=1$ implies that $\phi_1^{2^{N-1}}u(\tau,0)\subset \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n$ and $\phi_1^{2^{N-1}}u(\tau,1)\subset \phi_1(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n).$

Now what I am trying to understand is why if $\phi_1^{2^{N-1}}u\neq u$, then $\phi_1^{2^{N-1}}u$ cannot be a translation of $u$, i.e. it's not of the form $u(\tau+c,t)$. I think it has to do with the fact that $\psi_t$ is perpendicular to $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n $ and to $\psi_t(\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^n)$ but I am not sure how I can apply this.

An expression for $\psi_t([z_0:...:z_n])=[z_0:e^{i2\pi t}z_1:...:e^{i2\pi n t}z_n]$ but I am not sure it's helpfull.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even after two days this wording is hard for me to decipher. Are you asking: "Suppose $X\neq0$ is a Killing field of the Fubini-Study metric and orthogonal to $RP^n$ (perhaps the particular field of the edit), normalized so that if $\psi_t$ is its time-$t$ flow then $\psi_1$ is the identity. 'Subdivide' the flow into segments of time $2^{-N}$, consider 'sheets' formed by the time-$2^{-N}k$ images ($0\leq k\leq 2^N$) of $RP^n$, and let $u$ be a homotopy of a path in $RP^n$ to a path in the first sheet. If $u\neq\psi_{1/2}u$, then $\psi_{1/2}u$ is not a translate of $u$."?

Comment: Yes , I belive we coulod phrase that like that @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: We also have that $u$ is $J$-holomorphic and  that $\phi_1^{2^{N-1}}$ is $J$-holomorphic. @AndrewD.Hwang

Comment: Presumably $J$ is the standard complex structure on $CP^n$? Anyway, that property of $u$ is potentially an important detail. Is there anything else...? <> As an unrelated matter of style, it's customary to capitalize proper names such as Killing, Fubini, and Study (thus _Fubini-Study metric_, with a hyphen), and not to capitalize adjectives, such as holomorphic. (People sometimes joke that a mathematician has Truly Arrived when their name is not capitalized, usually restricted to Abel and Chern, but there are benefits to being consistent and mindful.)

Comment: Yeah maybe the fact they are $J$-holomorphic is important but I can't seem to prove it anyway trying to use that property. @AndrewD.Hwang